# Reading message from socket in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I try to understand reading from socket in C (Linux), this is only part of code:

```
while(success == 0) {

    while((n = read(sockfd, buffer, BUFFSIZE, 0)) > 0) {
        printf("%s",buffer);
        bzero(buffer,BUFFSIZE);
    }
    success = 1;
    printf("###");

}
```

The message is printed, but the three hashes (###) are never print? Why? The program seems to block on read(). Here i do just printing, but what i need to do is to buffer the whole message and then process it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The program on the *other end* of the socket is not [closing](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Closing-a-Socket.html) it, nor [shutting down](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/shutdown.html) its writes (which are your reads), so your end does not know that everything is finished - indeed, logically it *isn't* finished until the other end says there is nothing more for you to read.

Typically, your application level logic needs to know in advance how much to read, or reads until a certain terminator is received, or the other end gracefully closes or shuts down the socket.

(Non-blocking I/O is something else entirely - it allows you to do other things whilst reading from sockets efficiently in a single thread, but it doesn't solve the problem of determining when you've finished reading from a socket, which is your problem.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i am saving the message char by char into buffer and when i find newline i stop saving and process it :) then i clear the buffer and receive next line

Answer (score 5):

You need to know how large is the message you're receiving, and keep reading until you have the whole message (a read can return only part of your message).

```
do {
    nread = read(s, buf, to_read);
    if (nread < 0 && errno == EINTR)
            continue;
    if (nread < 0) {
            perror("read");
            exit(1);
    }

    if (nread == 0) {
            printf("socket closed");
            ... do something appropiate ...
            ... (reconnecting/exiting the loop with an error/...) ...
    }

    to_read -= nread;
    buf += nread;
} while (to_read > 0);
```

`to_read` is the length in bytes you're expecting to read. `buf` has enough space for it. After every read, update `to_read` and `buf` accordingly. And, of course, you should deal with errors correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to now when to stop reading from the socket, otherwise the socket will block your program until it receives more data. Have a look at non-blocking sockets if you want to know how to create sockets that don't block your program.

ief2

Comment: how will non-blocking IO solve the problem of knowing when you've read enough though?

Comment: A non-blocking socket will return an error code when there's no data available. I think this article is straight forward: http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/nonblocking.html

Comment: which usually means that data has not arrived yet, not that you have read a whole datagram/segment/message/whatever.

Comment: That's right, nevertheless what I say is also right! No data is available. For good comunication you will have to setup a protocol, even though it could be a small one, like only one 32 bit integer. Than you'd have to make sure you receive 4 bytes before continuing. Isn't that obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `\n`. Sometimes the non-ended lines are not printed.

EDIT: Oh wait you mean the program do not end?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your while loop never terminates because the read either succeeds or blocks.

Comment: i guess it blocks, but how to read the whole message into memory and then process it?

Comment: Exit the loop, e.g. while ((n = read(sockfd, buffer, BUFFSIZE, 0)) > 0 && !done)

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop will only end when n has the value zero.

When would you expect [read](http://linuxreviews.org/man/read/) to return the value zero?  Does the data you are sending to this socket satisfy any condition that would lead to read returning zero?